# how to download data from ECB using pandaSDMX?

Tags: pandas, sdmx

I am trying to download the NEER data from [this target page](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/balance_of_payments_and_external/eer/html/index.en.html).

Here is a good example:[Most efficient way of converting RESTful output to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895494/most-efficient-way-of-converting-restful-output-to-dataframe/59174391#59174391)

Here is the code to get the OECD data.

```
import pandasdmx as sdmx

df = sdmx.Request('OECD').data(
  resource_id='MEI_FIN',
  key='IR3TIB.GBR+USA.M',
  params={'startTime': '2008-06', 'dimensionAtObservation': 'TimeDimension'},
).write()
```

I just wonder where to find and how to search the 'resource_id', 'params' and 'key' to get the EUR NEER data in my target ECB page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

1. Find the data in https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/. If not, search other database.
2. Select and filter until I get the data series.
3. click the data series, it will show the data in a window. The url of this window gives me the key. https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=120.EXR.D.E5.EUR.EN00.A
4. Then use the key to download the data.

```
df = sdmx.Request('ECB').data(
    resource_id='EXR',
    key='D.E5.EUR.EN00.A',
    params=dict(startPeriod='2019-01', endPeriod='2019-06'),
).write()
```

The remaining question is that if I can search directly using the code instead of visiting the website.